# Hibernate issue to while subclass mapping - instantiate default tuplizer

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a User class and employee class where employee class extends and User class. also, I have an address class which is a HAS-A Relationship to both the classes. Below are the implementation classes and error. I am getting the error.

**User Model**

```
  public class User {
    private int userid;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Date dob;
    private String gender;
    private Set<Address> addresses;
//getter and setters
}
```

**Employee Model**

```
public class Employee extends User {
    private Date joindate;
    private String role;
    private Branch branch;
//getter and setters
}
```

**Address Model**

```
public class Address {
    private String email;
    private String mobile;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
    private String pin;
//getter & setters
}
```

**users.hbm.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.alok.mypro.model.usermodel.User" table="myuser" schema="mydb">
        <id name="userid">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" />
        <property name="password" />
        <property name="dob" />
        <property name="gender" />
        <set name="addresses" cascade="all">
            <key column="userid" />
            <one-to-many class="com.alok.mypro.model.usermodel.Address" />
        </set>

        <joined-subclass name="com.alok.mypro.model.usermodel.Employee" table="employee">
            <key column="userid" />
            <property name="joindate" />
            <property name="role" />
            <many-to-one name="branch" class="com.alok.mypro.model.places.Branch"/>
        </joined-subclass>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**address.hbm.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.alok.mypro.model.usermodel.Address" table="address"
        schema="myuser">

        <id name="email" />
        <property name="mobile" />
        <property name="street" />
        <property name="city" />
        <property name="state" />
        <property name="country" />
        <property name="pin" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Exception while building**

---

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
>       at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:108)
>       at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:133)
>       at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:80)
>       at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:322)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:485)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:126)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:87)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:286)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
>       at Test.main(Test.java:7)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:105)
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for addresses in class com.alok.mypro.model.usermodel.Employee
>       at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:326)
>       at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:320)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:304)
>       at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:297)
>       at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:155)
>       at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:77)
>       ... 14 more

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to a missing getter property.

You should add the following code to Address class

```
public Set<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }
```

moreover please check if you have also the setter property.

```
private void setAddresses(Set<Address> addresses) {
    this.addresses = addresses;
}
```

Hibernate basically needs getter and setter properties for attributes that need to be persisted, as described https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html/ch02.html#domainmodel-pojo-accessors .

You should make the setter private in order to enforce data encapsulation of your class during changes.

Comment: Getters and setters are there. However, Getter and Setter for address to be in User Model but issue showing on Employee Model.

{Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for addresses in class com.alok.mypro.model.usermodel.Employee at }

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem. Could you please share your Hibernate config file `hibernate.cfg.xml` ?